# play framework slick action crashes server

Tags: playframework, crash, slick-3.0

Running:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (MacOS BigSur everything ok)
- play framework version 2.7.4.
- play_slick 4.0.2
- either sqlite%3.34.0 or h2%1.4.192
- openjdk version "11.0.11" (MacOS: openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14)

I'm developing on Mac, the production environment is Ubuntu. On Mac everything works fine. On Ubuntu slick action crashes.
Here's the debug output from slick and hikari:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/home/robert/tourneyservice-1.4.6/lib/com.google.inject.guice-4.2.2.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[info] c.z.h.HikariDataSource - db - Starting...
[info] c.z.h.HikariDataSource - db - Start completed.

...

[debug] s.b.B.action - #1: StreamingInvokerAction$HeadOptionAction [select "id", "uuid", "club", "orgDir", "licStr", "email", "name", "address", "password", "reqTStamp", "allowContact", "fullVersion" from "LICENSE" where "orgDir" = 'exampleclub']
[debug] s.j.J.statement - Preparing statement: select "id", "uuid", "club", "orgDir", "licStr", "email", "name", "address", "password", "reqTStamp", "allowContact", "fullVersion" from "LICENSE" where "orgDir" = 'exampleclub'
```

After the slick action the play framework error handler gets invoked.
Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be related to the database difference in prod Vs local? Don't you have more logs? What does the error handler returns?

Comment: Many thanks, you gave me the crucial hint. I've had a custom error handler which tried to respond a page to an Ajax call (so I get an  Unexpected exception[ServerResultException: HTTP 1.0 client does not support chunked response]). I removed the error handler and I get the real reason: Unexpected exception[SQLTransientConnectionException: db - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.].

Answer (score 0):

Database was not available and I disabled play evolutions.